# How to sprites many svg (better way to load many svg) in website

Tags: html, css, image, performance, svg

I have a page that has about **200** `svg` images that are loads without scrolling. I want to know what is the better way to handle many images to increase performance of site.

- I know some libraries like [`lazyload`](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload) can load images when page scrolled. but I can't use this libraries, cause I havn't scroll.
- I know I can use image background positioning by `css`. but my images aren't in same file and they are separated.

Is there any idea to how can increase performance of my web page?

Comment: You can use sprites to reduce the http requests on each page load

Comment: @AlonEitan unfortunately my images are `svg` and I think can't use this method.

Comment: There is [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/) about svg sprites, perhaps it would be possible after all

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes. thank. can you send it as answer to I accept?

Comment: Sorry, but it was just a link to a tutorial `:)` Glad I could help, and perhaps you could post your own answer to the question when you're finished with explanation about how you solve it for future users having the same problem (I didn't downvote BTW)

Answer (score 2):

Make you own lazy load. It's not very diffifult and there are plenty of examples to be found how to do it.

You say you dont have a scroll, but because you're asking for something like that, I'm going to assume they're not all on your screen in one go. That likely means you have some events going to to switch content.

You need to make a "customLazyLoad_all_currently_visible_images" function, which you call on `window.ready` (or whatever you prefer) and also when you change the content of your page.

---

If you to preload all images in the images in the background, you can use the `window.ready` for that too. The window fires a ready each time a back is done. So on the first run you do the ones which are visible, and then you can do e.g. the next 25 images (possible with a little interval between them).

Or for a more resource efficient method, you can make your customLazyLoad to two thing: Load the currently visible images, and try to guess what the next images will be and only load those in the background. The "one step ahead loader" if you will.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got what you means. but in first view I need to show about 50 images. and really i need to handle requests.

Answer (score 1):

## Technical solution:

Use the [lazyload.js](https://github.com/tuupola/lazyload) and trigger it without scrolling by:

```
$(window).trigger("scroll");
```

## CDN:

If you have register your website with a CDN such as `cloudflare` they will cache your images and your performance will jump.

Comment: thanks. in question I said i cant use lazyload cause I havn't scoll. but the **CDN** is a little better.

Comment: as i told you you trigger it without scrolling with the code i mentioned